# Модальное окно с вопросом и двумя вариантами ответов

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы сайта вылазило модальное окно с вопросом и двумя вариантами ответов? Причём чтобы первая из них была по умолчанию активной, а на вторую можно было переключиться, нажав на стрелку на клавиатуре? Аналог, как в Windows, когда нажимаешь "Очистка корзины", например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
 var flag=confirm("Вопрос");
 if(flag){
  //если нажали "Да"...
 }
 else{
  //иначе...
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Rules!

Comment: Пожалуйста :)

Comment: Да кстати я чёто тоже забыл об этом сказать @Secvestr примите мой ответ (поставте галочку рядом !)

Comment: А вот и нет! @Secvestr слишком коварный....=)